# Upgrade to 16.04 - now won't boot

Tags: boot

I turn on the PC and just get a black screen which says:

"lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg--root clean, 377408/7118048 files, 2761813/28454712 blocks"

The PC just hangs with the cursor blinking at the start of the next line. Hitting ENTER does nothing.

I'm not a Linux expert and I'm completely ignorant as to what might have caused this and how to solve it. All help appreciated